# Process/Processor Synchronization without special instructions

Tags: multithreading, memory, multiprocessing, synchronization, cpu-architecture

My understanding is mutex in multi-core systems basically depend on being able to do an atomic compare + update operation. This consists of simultaneously checking the value of a flag and updating it at the same time and if two processors attempt it at the same time there is an ordering where one gets priority.

If you didn't have this special instruction, is there a way consistently share memory between processors?

Even in a multi-threaded application it seems a simple atomic write isn't sufficient.

Comment: Without RMWs, but with sequential consistency, you can implement a mutex. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm for two or more threads, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm for only two threads.  Or for some problems, release-store and acquire-load are sufficient, without needing atomic RMWs.  (e.g. a SeqLock for publishing a timestamp from a timer interrupt to multiple readers).  On x86 that doesn't require any special instructions, but on weakly-ordered ISAs you'd need barrier instructions.  (seq_cst isn't free even on x86, so no Dekker's Algorithm.)

Comment: Do you mean only without RMWs, or are you also excluding any special instructions that give ordering between separate operations from this thread?

Comment: Without RMW, barrier instructions are OK but I don't understand how they would solve the problem of simultaneous access.

Comment: See my first comment: with enough barriers to recover sequential consistency, you can implement a mutex using Dekker's or Peterson's algorithm.  You're right that you couldn't have lock-free atomic addition or whatever, but you can do stuff like setting a flag that tells other threads the data in a buffer is done writing so they can read it.  e.g. it's totally possible to write multi-threaded C++ programs that never use lock-free `std::atomic`, only `std::mutex`, with the only concurrent access to shared data being multiple readers.

Comment: Your model also allows C++ `std::atomic` `.load` and `.store`, which again is enough for some uses, or for parts of algorithms with limited use of a mutex.

Comment: If I have two processes wanting to write to the same location, how would this work to synchronize memory writes?

Comment: Same as in a C program: `mutex_lock(&lock); shared = 1; mutex_unlock(&lock);`.  All readers and writers have to respect the mutex, or see inconsistent data.  (Or just use it lock-free if you never need to do an atomic RMW on it.  If you just need pure writes, both threads can just do C++ `shared.store(1, std::memory_order_release);` or whatever)

Comment: The problem still is if you have two processes reading and updating the flag register at the same time. Unless you can atomically read and write in a single chunk I don't see how this works.

Comment: You avoid ever doing that by having all processes acquire a mutex before accessing a shared location.  Like C++ `std::atomic<bool>::is_lock_free() == false`.  Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm and understood that makes it possible to implement a mutex?   (It does require processes / threads to know which slot to use in the `flags[]` array, so some coordination is required when starting them.)

Comment: That sucks a lot, which is why essentially all SMP hardware provides at least a test-and-set or exchange which can implement C++ `std::atomic_flag`, and why everything from this century provides enough HW support for lock-free `atomic<int>`, e.g. via LL/SC or compare_exchange plus maybe some other operations like direct support for fetch_add.

Comment: I don't really believe this will work with multiple processors, ultimately how can you get away from the fact two processors can do the same thing simultaneously?

Comment: By using locking to have them *not* try to non-atomically-RMW the same location.  That would be a bug.  In C++ terms, data-race UB.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm works for multiple cores operating in parallel, in C++ terms requiring only `.store(value, seq_cst)` and `.load(seq_cst)`.  If you have an atomic RMW, that's an easier and more efficient way to get mutual exclusion, but it's not the only way.

Comment: The confusing this is if the secondary process sets the desire to enter flag right after the first process reads it. It seems you still have a problem....I will read it more closely later.

Comment: @FourierFlux: In that case, P0's writes to `flag[0]` and `turn` will therefore also precede P1's write to `flag[1]`, and therefore they also precede all the later operations in P1.  So P1 will read `flag[0] == true` (observing P0's earlier write), and will read `turn == 0` (observing its own write which is more recent than P0's), and thus P1 will spin instead of entering the critical section.